# shimano xc30 mtb spd shoes for CycloCross?

Tags: cyclocross

I am planning on attempting my first cyclocross race on the cheap and cant decide on what shoes. As it will be very muddy and rainy (like most British weather) I want to make sure I get the shoes with the right level of grip. Will these Shimano xc30 mtb be enough with a pair of studs in the front?

Answer (score 1):

If you throw some studs on those XC 30s ( don't skip that step ) you'll have plenty of grip and all around performance. Unless you travel into some higher price ranges where the really aggressive tread patterns usually live, you'll be hard pressed to find too much of a difference between MTB shoes and cross shoes.

If you end up in love with racing cross, you'll start to get a good handle on which equipment works best for you.

Comment: Yes, get studs for the front of the shoes.  This is really helpful during muddy run-up sections.

Comment: Any idea how you get the studs into the shoes?